# How to calculate needed length for adjacent paths between parallel rectangles?

Tags: geometry

This is the geometric task, a solution of which should help in drawing of a fonts. It is difficult for me to explain in title only what exactly problem is, so I drew some sketches.

Greens are known and red are required lengths. Yellow is the angle that I additionally would like to know, if reds are actually impossible to get faster.

[image: Task]

Currently I deal with it in bunch of steps that figured out by myself. I'm using Inkscape so some info is obtained with help of the Measure tool:

1. Draw parallels and get the length and the angle of the diagonal path between them.

[image: Step 1]

2. Draw rectangle of the received length and predefined thickness (height) and get it's inner diagonal angle.

[image: Step 2]

3. Get difference between two angles and move connection rectangle so its bottom left corner touches bottom right corner of the left parallel.

[image: Step 3]

4. Rotate connection rectangle anticlockwise using received angle and its bottom left corner as transformation origin point.

[image: Step 4]

5. Remove redundant shape parts.

[image: Step 5]

Now task is resolved as reds are known, but I feel that this is too long and very impractical way.

Comment: I presume you also know the distance between the inner edges of the Cyrillic I?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Yes, the inner rectangle dimensions are fully known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the figure below, you know $AE$ and $EB$ (the gap between vertical lines) and the thickness of the middle part, $BF$. Then:

1. In $\triangle ABE$ you can find $AB$ using Pythagoras' theorem
2. In $\triangle ABF$ you can find $\angle ABF$, using $\arccos$ function (you know the hypotenuse and the adjacent side). This is your yellow angle
3. $\angle BAC = 90^\circ-\angle ABF$
4. In $\triangle BAE$ get $\angle BAE$ using $\arctan$ function (you have the two sides)
5. $\angle CAE=\angle BAE-\angle BAC$
6. In $\triangle CAE$ find $CE$ using the tangent function, since you know $\angle CAE$ and side $AE$
7. $BC=BE-CE$

[image]